# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No block "form_start" found while rendering the form.")

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.1

I'm upgrading the symfony version from 2.1 to symfony3. I have made changes according to the new version but while rendering "form" in twig template I'm getting this error.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No block "form_start" found while rendering the form.")

In controller I have generated form like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyformType::class, $data, array(
        'readonly' => false,
    ));
```

And I have used this code in twig but getting same error:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{{ form_row(form.dueDate) }}

{{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'Submit me' }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Have you looked [mcve]?

Comment: `form_start()` is definitely still valid in Symfony 3.  You should show us what your Twig looks like, as well as how you create the form and send it to your template.

Comment: @Jason Roman I have edited code now Please check and let me know what is wrong with this?

Comment: That's odd. I know the 'readonly' option was deprecated but that shouldn't cause that error. Perhaps you're loading an old 1.x Twig version?

Comment: Are you extending another template? Did you miss out `{% body block %}` or another needed block?